# brewでnodeをインストールせずにyarnをupgradeする方法

Tags: javascript, macos, node.js, homebrew, yarn

nvmやndenvを使っている場合、brewでyarnをインストールするときはbrewでnodeが入らないように以下のように`--ignore-dependencies`をつけると思います。

```
$ brew install yarn --ignore-dependencies
```

この場合、yarnのupgradeはどのようにすればいいでしょうか？

以下、失敗した方法です。

```
$ brew upgrade yarn --ignore-dependencies
Error: invalid option: --ignore-dependencies
```

```
$ brew upgrade yarn # nodeが入ってしまう
```

Comment: 回答がないので英語版にマルチポストしました https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59858875/how-to-upgrade-yarn-without-node-with-brew

Comment: 英語版stackoverflowにて解決しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59858875/how-to-upgrade-yarn-without-node-with-brew

英語版stackoverflowにて解決しました。

ベストアンサーを引用します。

> You can self update yarn using the official provided curl script:
>
> ```bash
> curl --compressed -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
> ```
>
> See more about this [here](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/self-update/)